# node.js: external script called with exec terminates early when I use spawn instead

Tags: node.js, exec, spawn

When I use node to start my scanner like this, it works flawlessly:

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;
function scanner(response) {

 console.log("Request handler 'scanner' was called.");

 exec("scanimage --source 'Flatbed' -pv --format tiff --batch=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)_p%04d.tiff  --resolution 300 --batch-count=1", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
  console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
  response.end();
 });
}
```

Scanning works, this output is written:

```
Request handler 'scanner' was called.
stdout: 
stdout: Scanning 1 pages, incrementing by 1, numbering from 1
Scanning page 1
scanimage: scanning image of size 2552x3508 pixels at 24 bits/pixel
scanimage: acquiring RGB frame
scanimage: min/max graylevel value = 15/255
scanimage: read 26857248 bytes in total
Scanned page 1. (scanner status = 5)
```

Since scanning takes a while, especially for many pages I wanted to catch stdout in real-time to display a progress bar or similar in the web app. So I tried to get the console output with spawn:

```
function scanner(response) {
var exec = require("child_process").exec;

 console.log("Request handler 'scanner' was called.");

 var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    scanimage    = spawn('scanimage', ['--source', 'Flatbed', '-pv', '--format', 'tif','--batch=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)_p%04d.tiff','--resolution', '600', '--mode', 'Gray', '--batch-count=1']);
 scanimage.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
   console.log('stdout: ' + data);
 });

 scanimage.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
   console.log('stderr: ' + data);
 });

 scanimage.on('exit', function (code) {
   console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
 });
}
```

However, now the scan won't even start but the first line of the output seems correct:

```
Request handler 'scanner' was called.
stderr: Scanning 1 pages, incrementing by 1, numbering from 1

child process exited with code null
```

What's strange is that "Scanning 1 pages, incrementing by 1, numbering from 1" now comes from stderr and that the process exits thereafter.

Any idea how to debug this?

Comment: I'm curious about this as well and running into a similar problem. Did you perhaps solve it already?

Comment: @RobinPapa In the end I just created a bash script on the server that runs the same command I would have called with "exec". Since I wanted to get the scan progress, a value which is given to stderr, I appended the following commands to the **end** of the command: `2>&1 | stdbuf -oL tr '\r' '\n'`.

So spawn command now calls `scanimage = spawn('bash', ['./scanscript.sh'])`

and inside scanscript.sh I have:
`scanimage --source 'Flatbed' -pv --format tiff --batch=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)_p%04d.tiff  --resolution 300 --batch-count=1 2>&1 | stdbuf -oL tr '\r' '\n'`